# Как через физику реализовать рывок (перекат) персонажа Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d

Есть такой вот код

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movementSpeed = 5f;
    private float dashForce;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    public Vector3 moveDirection;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        dashForce = movementSpeed * 10;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        // Передвижение
        float directionX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float directionZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        moveDirection = new Vector3(directionX, 0, directionZ);

        rb.velocity = moveDirection * movementSpeed;

        // Рывок
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            rb.AddForce(moveDirection * dashForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Я попытался сделать рывок приложением силы, но персонаж вместо плавного перемещения просто телепортируется вперед, как это можно исправить или сделать правильнее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используете передвижение посредством изменения скорости, то и делайте это дальше, не нужно использовать `AddForce`. В вашем случае, лучше использовать [корутину](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/Manual/Coroutines.html) чтобы перекат был плавным и `AnimationCurve`, чтобы иметь возможность настроить изменение скорости переката со временем. Вот пример кода, основанном на вашем:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]// Нужно, чтобы желаемый компонент всегда был на Gameobject, к которому прикреплен данный скрипт
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _movementSpeed = 5f; // [SerializeField] делает private поля видимыми в инспекторе
    [SerializeField] private float _dashSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private AnimationCurve _dashSpeedCurve;
    [SerializeField] private float _dashTime = 0.5f;

    private Rigidbody _rb;
    private bool _isDashing;

    private void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); // Если получаете компонент через GetComponent, то делайте RequireComponent(typeof(ТипКомпонента))
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var directionX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var directionZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        var moveDirection = new Vector3(directionX, 0, directionZ);

        Move(moveDirection, _movementSpeed);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            StartCoroutine(Dash(moveDirection));
        }

    }

    private void Move(Vector3 direction, float speed)
    {
        if (direction == Vector3.zero) return;
        if (_isDashing) return;

        ApplyVelocity(direction, speed);
    }

    private IEnumerator Dash(Vector3 direction)
    {
        if (direction == Vector3.zero) yield break;
        if (_isDashing) yield break;

        _isDashing = true;

        var elapsedTime = 0f;
        while (elapsedTime < _dashTime)
        {
            var velocityMultiplier = _dashSpeed * _dashSpeedCurve.Evaluate(elapsedTime);

            ApplyVelocity(direction, velocityMultiplier);

            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time.deltaTime);
        }
        _isDashing = false;
        yield break;
    }

    private void ApplyVelocity(Vector3 desiredVelocity, float multiplier) // Дублирующийся код всегда выносить в отдельный метод
    {
        var velocity = _rb.velocity;

        velocity.y = desiredVelocity.y == 0 ? velocity.y : desiredVelocity.y * multiplier;// чтобы не ломать физику, скорость по Y будет изменяться только если это нужно
        velocity.x = desiredVelocity.x * multiplier;
        velocity.z = desiredVelocity.z * multiplier;

        _rb.velocity = velocity;
    }

}
```

Начну по порядку. `ApplyVelocity` - устанавливает желаемую скорость свойству `velocity` компонента `Rigidbody`. Здесь я использовал [тернарный оператор](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), чтобы изменять скорость по оси Y только в случае, если это нужно делать (допустим для прыжка), таким образом, физика не будет ломаться и объект не будет летать в воздухе при движении. Так как этот код у меня повторялся дважды, я вынес его в отдельный удобный метод.

Далее метод `Move`. Проверяет направление движения и, если оно равно нулю, то ничего не делает. Не дает возможность двигаться, если персонаж находится в перекате. И просто применяет скорость, на основании направления и желаемой скорости.

Собственно, сама корутина `Dash`. Проверяет направление и возможность переката и отключается, если что-то не так. Если все хорошо, устанавливает `_isDashing` в значение true, обозначая этим то, что персонаж в перекате. Далее создает переменную, которая отвечает за время, прошедшее с начала переката и, пока это время меньше, чем время которое должен длиться перекат: определяет скорость персонажа, путем умножения желаемой скорости на значение кривой в elapsedTime времени (Когда будете настраивать кривую, поймете что это означает), далее применяет скорость, увеличивает прошедшее время на `Time.deltaTime` секунд и ожидает `Time.deltaTime` секунд. Когда цикл завершится (прошедшее время будет больше или равно времени переката), присваивает `_isDashing` значение false, что означает, что перекат завершился и останавливает сама себя.

В методе `Update` я, как и вы, определяю направление движения, двигаю объект, и, если нажата клавиша переката, стартую корутину переката.

Как у меня выглядят анимационная кривая и настройки скрипта: [image: введите сюда описание изображения. Нет.]

Еще совет, если вам хочется написать комментарий к куску кода, чтобы объяснить для чего он нужен, как в этом случае:

```
// Передвижение
float directionX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
...
```

То выносите этот код в отдельный метод с названием, которое описывает что он делает. Также, старайтесь избегать публичных полей и свойств, чтобы нельзя было изменить состояние объекта как угодно откуда угодно.

Comment: `yield break`, `yield break`, а сразу в `if` на старт корутины проверить нельзя? а еще лучше кешировать корутину в поле и просто проверить на `null`, вместо флага `_isDashing`, плюс будет возможность ее прервать в сценарии хита или еще каком. `ApplyVelocity` вообще быть не должно, `velocity` в `FixedUpdate` меняют, а в корутине только множитель `_currentVelocityMultiplier` меняем.

Comment: @АлександрДьячков Сделайте так, как написал Ярослав сверху, чтобы не просто скопипастить код, а понять как все работает. Будут вопросы, пищите сюда.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!
У меня вопрос вот по этой строчке: 
var velocityMultiplier = _dashSpeed * _dashSpeedCurve.Evaluate(elapsedTime);
Что за метод Evaluate?

Comment: @АлександрДьячков [Evaluate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.Evaluate.html) Возвращает значение кривой в указанный момент времени. Это как с графиком, вы вводите координату по X и получаете координату этого графика по Y.